# How to Download a file from s3 bucket using java with AWS temporary credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have this code to download a file from s3 bucket to tmp space of lambda server.

```
String url = "https://slack-automation.s3.amazonaws.com/slack.xlsx";

URL link = new URL(url);

/* //AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
   AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build() ;
   S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
   InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
   // Process the objectData stream.
   objectData.close();
 */

// Code to download
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;

while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
    out.write(buf, 0, n);
}

out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/" + fileName);
fos.write(response);
fos.close();
file = new File("/tmp/" + fileName);

//file = new File(filePath);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
workBookSheet = workBook.getSheet(workBook.getSheetName(0));
rowCount = workBookSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
formatter = new DataFormatter();
```

But the problem is to access this file, the public permission has to be given.

How can I download this file to lambda server tmp space by getting the temporary credentials which is given over here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html

I am unable to achieve, can somebody please help me with the code to download file with temporary credentials without passing my accesskey and secretkey just like in the method mentioned above?

Thanks Akshay Sing , i dont know how to comment with a code, the code which i tried after your answer is here

public void setupWorkbook(String filePath) throws IOException {

```
    String clientRegion = "eu-central-1";
    String roleARN = "myAwsArnRoleOverHere";
    String roleSessionName = "slackautomation";
    String bucketName = "slack-automation";
    String key = "slack.xlsx";


    String fileName = "slack.xlsx";



    try {

        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                                                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                                                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                                                .build();

        AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                                                .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                                                .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);
        stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);

        // Start a session.
        GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
        // The duration can be set to more than 3600 seconds only if temporary
        // credentials are requested by an IAM user rather than an account owner.
        getSessionTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(900);
        GetSessionTokenResult sessionTokenResult = stsClient.getSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);
        Credentials sessionCredentials = sessionTokenResult.getCredentials();

        // Package the temporary security credentials as a BasicSessionCredentials object 
        // for an Amazon S3 client object to use.
        BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(), sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

        // Provide temporary security credentials so that the Amazon S3 client 
        // can send authenticated requests to Amazon S3. You create the client 
        // using the basicSessionCredentials object.
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicSessionCredentials))
                                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                                .build();

        // Verify that assuming the role worked and the permissions are set correctly
        // by getting a set of object keys from the bucket.
        ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName);

        System.out.println("No. of Objects: " + objects.getObjectSummaries().size());
        S3Object fileObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));         
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileObject.getObjectContent());

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int n = 0;

        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {

            out.write(buf, 0, n);

        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/" + fileName);

        fos.write(response);

        fos.close();
        file = new File("/tmp/" + fileName);

        //file = new File(filePath);

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        workBookSheet = workBook.getSheet(workBook.getSheetName(0));

        rowCount = workBookSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        formatter = new DataFormatter();


    }
    catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
        // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
        // it, so it returned an error response.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SdkClientException e) {
        // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
        // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it is not working it is throwing an error over "stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);"

error with just the line number not much clue for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution for my above question, i am writing the entire code over here

```
public void setupWorkbook(String filePath) throws IOException {



   // String bucketName = "slack-automation";
    String key = "slack.xlsx";


    String fileName = "slack.xlsx";


    String bucketName = System.getenv("bucket_name");

    try {



        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

        ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName);

        System.out.println("No. of Objects: " + objects.getObjectSummaries().size());
        S3Object fileObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));         
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileObject.getObjectContent());

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

        int n = 0;

        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {

            out.write(buf, 0, n);

        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/" + fileName);

        fos.write(response);

        fos.close();
        file = new File("/tmp/" + fileName);

        //file = new File(filePath);

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        workBookSheet = workBook.getSheet(workBook.getSheetName(0));

        rowCount = workBookSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        formatter = new DataFormatter();


    }
    catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
        // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
        // it, so it returned an error response.
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("FIRST EXCEPTION"+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(SdkClientException e) {
        // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
        // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("SECOND EXCEPTION"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

It was just this part of the code was required to add

```
   AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();

    ObjectListing objects = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName);

    System.out.println("No. of Objects: " + objects.getObjectSummaries().size());
    S3Object fileObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));         
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fileObject.getObjectContent());
```

The line "AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client()" would assume the IAM Role and will get the temporary credentials without passing my accesskey and secretkey since the code is running from AWS Lambda. That's it, Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using the below procedure to download images from my S3 bucket and storing them to return a zip of the images to the user. I am excluding the zip-creation code for you:

To download the file to your temporary server, you must first obtain access to the `S3Object` you need. In your case, it is `slack.xlsx` stored on the `slack-automation` bucket.

You mentioned that you want to use the temporary credentials supplied to you by the IAM role. It's a smart move to not disclose credentials in code and simultaneously ensure that the credentials supplied to the service will be refreshed automatically. You'll need to initialise your `s3Client`
like this:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

The `InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` loads credentials from the Amazon EC2 Instance Metadata Service(based on your IAM role).

**Note**: Make sure that the IAM role being used actually has read-access to the bucket.

To obtain the `S3Object`, use this:

```
S3Object fileObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
```

In your case, the `bucketName` would be slack-automation and the key would be the name of the file on the S3 bucket(slack.xlsx here).

Then, to store the file on your server, use the `copyInputStreamToFile` function from `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(s3Object.getObjectContent(), new File(fileName));
```

Comment: i have modified my question with the changes you suggested, but still not working

Comment: What is the error that occurs @SinarK.K? Can you post an error message that you may have encountered?

Comment: Glad to hear you have a solution to your problem now. In case you feel that my answer was helpful or correct, upvote or Accept my answer accordingly.  

If need be, post the complete solution in a separate answer instead of just editing the question so that others will benefit from it.

Comment: thanks , i have got the correct solution for the same, i will upload the answer